# Why ShowContextMenu is not triggered in CDHtmlDialog?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, dialog, webbrowser-control

> -----------------------------------Update---------------------------------------
>   I guesee it is something related with PDF. Before the pdf is displayed, all functions work fine and all of them can be triggered. But after pdf is displayed, they won't work. So I think pdf itself is an activeX control.
>   ------------------------------------Update-----------------------------------------

I need to embed a html viewer in a dialog in my project.
But this html view will navigate to a pdf file, and my code works for it.
However, evey time when I right click on the pdf in the dialog, it always display the context menu like following:
[image]
Here is part of my code, I add break point inside `STDMETHOD(ShowContextMenu)`, but this is function is never triggered. Isn't it a callback function? How to disable the right click or the context menu ?

```
class TestHtmlViewer : public CDHtmlDialog
{
public:
TestHtmlViewer() {};
~TestHtmlViewer() {};

void Navigate(LPCTSTR URL, VARIANT* pFlags = nullptr, VARIANT* pTargetFrameName = nullptr, VARIANT* pPostData = nullptr, VARIANT* pHeaders = nullptr) const;

STDMETHOD(ShowContextMenu)(DWORD dwID, POINT *ppt, IUnknown *pcmdtReserved, IDispatch *pdispReserved) override
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(dwID);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(ppt);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pcmdtReserved);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pdispReserved);
    return S_OK;
};
};
```

I also tried the following function, but it is also not being called:

```
BOOL TestHtmlViewer::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
if (pMsg->message == WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK)
{
    return FALSE;
}

return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

Comment: [Delegate and interface map macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/delegate-and-interface-maps). It seems that you fail to see the relationship between MFC and the systems it abstracts (like COM). Make sure to get a complete reference on MFC before going any further. I'd recommend Jeff Prosise' [Programming Windows with MFC ](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0072850574).

Comment: I copy/pasted your `ShowContextMenu` code and it disables the context menu as expected. I tried it with a simple html file. Show how your pdf file is embedded, maybe there is some odd pdf issue. For `PreTranslateMessage` you want to return `TRUE`, also add a handler for `WM_RBUTTONDOWN`, and you have to handle the "context menu key" on the keyboard. But `ShowContextMenu` should do the job.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani  I guess that's the pdf issues. Before the pdf is displayed, when I right click on it, all functions work. But after pdf is displayed, these functions won't b triggered anymore.